# How can I get related objects for related objects of an object in Django in a single query when all linked using Generic Foreign Key

Tags: django

Assuming I have the following models and knowing that each Message can have multiple Records and each Record can have multiple Notes, how can I get a queryset of related Notes from a Message in a single query?

```
class Note:
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class Record:
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    notes = GenericRelation(Note, related_query_name='records')


class Message:
    records = GenericRelation(Record, related_query_name='messages')
```

I know how to achieve this by using list comprehensions like shown below, however it is a bad approach since this will do multiple queries.

```
if records := message.records.all():
    notes = list(chain.from_iterable([record.notes.all() for record in records]))
```

Comment: Are there other models that make use of the generic foreign key relationships in your data model? If not, then I'd suggest switching to typical `ForeignKey`'s and using `select_related` / `prefetch_related`.

Comment: Yes there are other models that make use of all generic foreign keys, that is why it's designed this way.

Comment: Take a look at [prefetch_related_objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related-objects)

Comment: I had to use prefetch_related but this works slightly different than I thought. Is there any way to get the notes straight away ? If i do the prefetch_related, this will prefetch the related objects in a single query but i will still have to loop through to extract the Notes out of them. I am looking for a way to get the list of notes straight away as I would do it writing pure SQL statement.